# Problem debugging Deno using VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running inside WSL-2: --inspect-brk being removed

Tags: visual-studio-code, deno, wsl-2

I am trying to debug Deno using VSCode on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running inside WSL-2. I setup my launch.json as described in [the Deno manual](https://deno.land/manual/tools/debugger#vscode):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Deno",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "-A", "${fileBasename}"],
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

however when I launch Deno the "--inspect-brk" option is being stripped out from the command used to launch Deno. If I modify my launch.json to change the option to "inspect-brk" (removing the leading --) the option shows up on the command line and I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve module "file:///mnt/c/Users/mlwp/projects/deno/inspect-brk"
```

Similarly if I change the name of the option to be "--inspect-brk-fun" then I get the message:

```
Found argument '--inspect-brk-fun' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

Anyone know why VSCode would strip the option or how to debug this

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your issue was an [incompatibility](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/12#issuecomment-656406826) with `--inspect-brk` in previous versions of the VSCode JavaScript debugger. It has been fixed some time ago and so have the [Deno docs](https://deno.land/manual@v1.10.0/getting_started/debugging_your_code#vscode) on this matter, where the value of `type` has changed and `port` has been replaced with `attachSimplePort` in `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Deno",
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "-A", "${file}"],
      "attachSimplePort": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I've found that using your current configuration should also work on newer releases (1.47+) of VSCode (running on Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL 2).